# Media library quick/inline edit

Tags: attachments, media

Posts and pages offers the opportunity for inline editing (Quick Edit), i.e [like this](https://wpcompendium.org/wordpress-basics/how-to-use-the-wordpress-quick-edit-feature/). It is also possible for custom post types, but for some reason this is not offered for attachments/the media library. Is there a way to enable quick edit for the media library (attachment post type)?

Comment: "Bulk edit image alt tag, caption & description – WordPress Media Library Helper by Codexin" extension exists now https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-helper/

Comment: @salient.salamander, It's been some months already but no answer of your question, I'm also looking for this and couldn't find any good solution even any code. Do you have any update how did you manage that please?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the List View, you can use the Grid View by clicking the icon with 4 squares at the top of the Media Library when viewing all items.

[image]

When clicking on an item, a modal will appear. It has navigation arrows at the top to left you quickly navigate items. Edits are saved automatically via AJAX, so while this is not technically the same as the Quick Edit for typical post types, it may be a time saver.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does make it a little faster. Still, one could wish WP was more consistent. Why on earth no quick or bulk editing of attachments? Few things could need it more... I'll leave this open for a few days, but if nothing comes up, your answer's it.